# Entity Framework Core: Performance when querying while including child collections

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core

I have a problem figuring out why a certain query results in a huge performance difference (300milliseconds vs. 30seconds) compared to querying the same data in different way. The same data is returned from both queries. I am using `EF Core 5.0.4`.

I have narrowed the problem down to the following EF Core definitions. I have a `ParentEntity` and a `ChildEntity`. My test database contains lots of parents and children, but the following examples use a single `ParentEntity` that has ~130,000 `ChildEntity`s.

```
    [Table("ParentTable")]
    public class ParentEntity
    {
        public static int Created = 0;

        public ParentEntity()
        {
            Created++;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public IList<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ChildTable")]
    public class ChildEntity
    {
        public static int Created = 0;

        public ChildEntity()
        {
            Created++;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public ParentEntity ParentRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentChildContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ParentEntity> Parents { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=True")
                .LogTo(s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));
        }
    }
```

I want to query a single `ParentEntity` with its `ChildEntity`s. Since the original query I tried to write was more complex, I tried to do it in a single query against the `DbSet`. That's also why the `AsSplitQuery` is in there. Leaving it out has no measurable performance impact.

```
using (var context = new ParentChildContext())
{
      ParentEntity.Created = ChildEntity.Created = 0;

      var sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      var parent = context.Parents
            .Where(p => p.Id == Guid.Parse("804FAE75-49EF-4A27-A276-FB08B2640432"))
            .Include(a => a.Children)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .First();

      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine($"Single Linq-Query took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
      Console.WriteLine($"Created: Parent = {ParentEntity.Created}, Child = {ChildEntity.Created}");
}
```

This results in an execution time of roughly 30 seconds. It properly gives me a single `ParentEntity` with 130k `ChildEntity`s, but 260k instances of `ChildEntity` are created. If I leave out `AsSplitQuery`, the performance is the same, but only 130k instances of `ChildEntity` are created.

When I query the same data in 2 separate steps, I get completely different numbers.

```
using (var context = new ParentChildContext())
{
      ParentEntity.Created = ChildEntity.Created = 0;

      var sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      var parent = context.Parents
            .Where(p => p.Id == Guid.Parse("804FAE75-49EF-4A27-A276-FB08B2640432"))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .First();

      var children = context.Children
            .Where(c => c.ParentRef.Id == Guid.Parse("804FAE75-49EF-4A27-A276-FB08B2640432"))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();

      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine($"2 Linq-Queries took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
      Console.WriteLine($"Created: Parent = {ParentEntity.Created}, Child = {ChildEntity.Created}");
}
```

This completes in roughly 300ms. I get the same data: 1 `ParentEntity`, 130k `ChildEntity`s.

I have no idea what is happening here inside `EF Core` that leads to such a drastic performance loss. The generated `SQL statements` look fine. When I execute them in `SSMS`, they give me the correct amount of rows (1 for the `ParentTable`, 130k for the `ChildTable`) and they complete in less than 1second.

This difference in performance doesn't seem right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you loading 130K entities? That's the problem, not `Include`. There's no scenario where using an ORM to load 130K *objects* would make sense. If you really want to retrieve 130K rows it means you have an ETL problem and you *really* need to treat those as rows, not objects. That means reading them in a stream using eg a DbDataReader, processing the data in batches, or eg exporting them to disk without using a lot of RAM

Comment: It is a problem when 2 ways of querying the same data result in vastly different performance. The original problem used paging and not loading everything at once, but it had roughly the same performance problem. This is the simplest form that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What if you use `.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()` instead of `.AsNoTracking()` in split query?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you try to enter a submarine from the driver or passenger seat. It has no seats. If you need 130K rows, you don't have an ORM problem. Besides, the various queries are *very* different. Why use `.AsSplitQuery()` ? Or query `Children` only, including the parent? Have you checked the actual SQL queries generated? I suspect what you did resulted in 1 query per child

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mentioned in my question that the SQL queries that are generated look fine and very similar in nature and return the data in less than 1 second.

Comment: @IvanStoev it makes no difference

Comment: BTW since you really want the *children*, you could use `Find` to load the parent then use [explicit loading with `Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) to load all related children.

Comment: @davidm SQL doesn't return hierarchical results, so EF has to reconstruct the parent/child hierarchy from the results. If it uses an INNER JOIN to return both parent and child results, it will have to extract the parent entities from the flat results. If the parent and children are loaded separately, it will have to "attach" the parent to the children.

Comment: @davidm which means the queries aren't similar. A single query with INNER JOIN is very different from two separate queries, one for the parent and one for the related entities

Comment: @davidma and once again, when you have 130K rows you don't have an ORM problem any more. You don't have individual objects with children, you have big result sets with relations. You need to use very different data access patterns - stream processing, paging, batching.

Comment: @davidm even in ML scenarios where the data *is* loaded in memory, it's always as dataframes, usually in columnar formats to reduce the amount of RAM used. OO and data don't exactly match, and lots of data is just one case where the impedance mismatch becomes too great.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not arguing your point about using other access strategies. I used paging, it resulted in the same-ish performance difference, and I removed paging to make the example I posted simpler. What you're saying is that it is understandable that reading 1row + 130k rows into an object model takes less than a second, but having EF Core match them up takes 30 seconds? I'm really struggling to understand that. I understand it takes longer AND there might be better ways to achieve what I tried to achive, but I do not understand 30 seconds.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please let do not change the OP subject/issue. 130K objects nowadays are nothing. ORM should be able to load them w/o any problem. As it does in the second scenario provided by OP.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't change the subject. This is the subject. ORMs are built to work with small object graphs, not streams of rows. No matter how good an ORM is, there's always an impedance mismatch between hierarchical objects and relational databases.  Even when tracking is enabled (which isn't the case here) the structures and algorithms used are tuned and *tested* for small object graphs. 30 seconds sounds a *lot* like EF has to search for parents using brute force. Isn't that why you suggested `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` ? To avoid the brute-force search?

Comment: @davidm try profiling the application to see what's going on. Even executing it and looking at the CPU/RAM graph in the [Diagnostics Tool window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/) will show if EF is wasting CPU and RAM to reconstruct the graph.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So I did fire up ANTS. Not sure why I haven't done that before, I was probably too focused on something being wrong with my model. It indeed shows that it iterates the children list a gazillion times. Changing Children from IList to HashSet solves the performance issue. I'll try to debug into it to find out the reason why it has to iterate the childrens list over and over, especially in the case of AsSplitQuery and AsNoTracking.

Comment: So it seems EF Core internally is not optimized to use Lists, but rather HashSets. It will use a HashSet if the navigation is defined as ICollection<T>. So in the end I think it was my model that was incorrect, using IList<T> as the navigation type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Since you helped me find the right answer, can you post an answer? I'll accept that as an answer then. Can't accept comments as the right answer. Also if you have any material about why this specific example is not ORM-friendly, please feel free to post it as well, I'd be very interested in getting to know more about that (I'm currently still with the belief that this should be supported with ORMs, but I'm willing to be wrong)

Comment: @davidm This really needs to go to EF Core issue tracker. At the end, there are 2 EF Core issues/bugs identified. (1) `AsNoTracking()` combined with `AsSolitQuery()` creates (and populates!) child entity instances which are 2x number of the returned records. While this is not the performance bottleneck, and is solved with `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()`, it's still annoying and is good to be fixed (2) The issue with the big child list. The slow quadratic search for "eliminating equal references with the same key" :-/ Changing `IList<T>` to ICollection<T>` solves it, but why they do it?